# How to declare a sympy Piecewise with multiple limits for multiple variables

Tags: sympy

In sympy, how do I declare a `Piecewise` function with multiple limits for multiple variables in a sub-function?

Here is my context and attempt:

```
from sympy import Piecewise, Symbol, exp
from sympy.abc import z
x1 = Symbol('x1')
x2 = Symbol('x2')
f = 2*pow(z,2)*exp(-z*(x1 + x2 + 2))
p = Piecewise((f, z > 0 and x1 > 0 and x2 > 0), (0, True))
```

And the error I receive is:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-5e3db02fe3dc> in <module>()
----> 1 p = Piecewise((f, z > 0 and x1 > 0 and x2 > 0), (0, True))

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\relational.py in __nonzero__(self)
    193 
    194     def __nonzero__(self):
--> 195         raise TypeError("cannot determine truth value of Relational")
    196 
    197     __bool__ = __nonzero__

TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah, there is a sympy `And` function for this:

```
from sympy import Piecewise, Symbol, exp, And
from sympy.abc import z
x1 = Symbol('x1')
x2 = Symbol('x2')
f = 2*pow(z,2)*exp(-z*(x1 + x2 + 2))
p = Piecewise((f, And(z > 0, x1 > 0, x2 > 0)), (0, True))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `&` as well:

```py
from sympy import Piecewise, Symbol, exp
from sympy.abc import z
x1 = Symbol('x1')
x2 = Symbol('x2')
f = 2 * pow(z,2) * exp(-z * (x1 + x2 + 2))
p = Piecewise((f, (z > 0) & (x1 > 0) & (x2 > 0)), (0, True))
```

There are more examples in [their documentation](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/elementary.html#piecewise).